# DocuSign JavaScrip Button - Hard Code User /Contact

Tags: javascript, custom-button, quote, docusign

I am using DocuSign on quotes that should create an envelope and add Contact user (associated with Quote record) and a static user (or contact) 'John wilson'. Ie. Signer 1 should be contact on record and Signer 2 should always be 'John Wilson'.

I have worked out how to bring in Signer 1 - from quote record, but not the static user 'John Wilson. Any ideas?

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("apex/dsfs__DocuSign_JavaScript")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/24.0/connection.js")}



//********* Option Declarations (Do not modify )*********//
var sourceId = DSGetPageIDFromHref(); var RQD = DSGetPageIDFromHref(); var RC = ''; var RSL = ''; var RSRO = ''; var RROS = ''; var CCRM = ''; var CCTM = ''; var CCNM = ''; var CRCL = ''; var CRL = ''; var OCO = ''; var DST = ''; var LA = ''; var CEM = ''; var CES = ''; var STB = ''; var SSB = ''; var SES = ''; var SEM = ''; var SRS = ''; var SCS = ''; var RES = '';
//*************************************************//
CCRM = 'Executive Sponsor~Signer 1';
RROS = '1';
CRL = encodeURIComponent("RoutingOrder~1;Email~{!User.Email};SignInPersonName~{!Contact.Name};SignNow~1,LoadDefaultContacts~0");

CCTM = 'Executive Sponsor~Sign in Person';
LA = '0';
OCO = 'Send';
//*************************************************//

window.location.href = "/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=0&SourceID=" + sourceId + "&RQD=" + RQD + "&CCTM=" + CCTM + "&CRL=" + CRL + "&CCRM=" + CCRM;
```

Comment: What does var RQD Define here?

Answer (score 0):

You could hard-code the static user's information into the CRL parameter...but there's a better way.

You can create a Hierarchy custom setting that contains the static user's information (you could just put it at the organization level).

From there, you should be able to access the custom setting via a merge field, in your javascript button, like `{!$Setup.HierarchyCustomSettingName.FieldName}`.

Using a custom setting allows you to (safely) change the static user without touching the Javascript.

The other part is that DocuSign separates different 'signers' in the CRL parameter by a comma.
To inject a second signer into the CRL parameter, your code would look like this

```
CRL = encodeURIComponent("RoutingOrder~1;Email~{!User.Email};SignInPersonName~{!Contact.Name};SignNow~1,Email~{!$Setup.HierarchyCustomSettingName.EmailField};SignInPersonName~{!$Setup.HierarchyCustomSettingName.StaticUserName};SignNow~1,LoadDefaultContacts~0");
```

CCRM and CCTM work a little differently, separated by a semicolon (I think), and you'll need to update these as well to accommodate a second signer. The [DocuSign Custom Button Quick Start Guide](https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/docusign-for-salesforce-custom-button-logic.pdf) should be able to guide you for those parameters.